# How to unmarshal/parse a request using Go correctly?

Tags: go

How to parse a curl request response in Golang correctly? I have tried the following where I send a request to an api and its response is:

```
{
  "Certificates": [
    {
      
      "Name": "some-name.here",
      .......
    }
  ],
  "DataRange": "Certificates 1 - 1",
  "TotalCount": 1
}
```

Now I want to use the Name in the Certificates in a string variable. i.e match. Before even I get to the looping through of the response, I get the error: `json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type []program.Item`. This error is coming from json.Unmarshal function where I pass my []bytes and the struct to use the bytes. Am I doing this correctly?

```golang
type Item struct {
    Certificates []CertificatesInfo
}

type CertificatesInfo struct {
    Name string
}

func main() {
        url := .....
        req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
        resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
        if err != nil {
            // handle err
            continue
        }
        defer resp.Body.Close()

        bodyBytes, err := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)

        if err != nil {
            continue
        }

        var ItemInfo []Item
        if err := json.Unmarshal(bodyBytes, &ItemInfo); err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to parse %v", err)
        }

        for _, infos := range ItemInfo {
            for _, names := range infos.Certificates {
                infraId:= names.Name
                match:= display_name
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: based on the json you posted it seems you receive a single `Item` and not a slice, so try passing t the json.Unmarshal `var ItemInfo Item` instead of `var ItemInfo []Item`

Comment: <https://go.dev/play/p/ZtmVZkrlQnw>

Comment: @knetsi its giving me an error on ItemInfo range in the next step if I change the ItemInfo to only Item instead of [].

Comment: @aquaticdigest yeah you don't have to loop though ItemInfo remove the `for _, infos := range ItemInfo {` loop

Comment: @knetsi Do i not need to do even this? ```bodyBytes, err := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)``` because when I print the bodybytes, they are printed like [12 43 ...] something like this. Or can I convert these to string using ```dec := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(string(bodyBytes)))```

Comment: @aquaticdigest, you just do `json.NewDecoder(resp.Body)`. I think you need to at least read ["Effective Go"](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html) to understand how interfaces work in Go. Basically, you should start with <https://go.dev/tour/>, then read Effective Go and then http://gopl.io would not hurt as well.

Comment: @knetsi sorry to bother again but how do I save the resp in a variable that is expecting string. Because its of type struct right. In your example, you have 2 Names, I am only expecting 1 Name field and nothing more. How do i convert the resp to string from this struct, i.e take the Name from the struct and put into a new var of type string. If I type cast to string it says: ```cannot convert resp (variable of type struct{Certificates []struct{Name string}}) to type string```

Comment: Oh, man. Please, _please_ start from the Go tour and get an entry-level book on Go. You're asking about such basic things I'm not sure there's anything to do here: you just lack the very basic knowledge about the programming language you're using. I do understand it's not easy to accept but that's how the things currently appear to be. You should work yourself through some education on these matters. There's no other way to become even barely proficient in programming.

Answer (score 0):

There's a mismatch between your sample JSON response data (a single object containing a list of certificates), and your code, which is expecting a list of objects, each of which contain a list of certificates).

Assuming that your JSON example is correct, this bit:

```
var ItemInfo []Item
if err := json.Unmarshal(bodyBytes, &ItemInfo); err != nil {
. . .
```

should probably be

```
var itemInfo Item
if err := json.Unmarshal(bodyBytes, &ItemInfo); err != nil {
. . .
```

Works on my machine:

https://go.dev/play/p/8FqIif1zzsQ

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    resp := Item{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &resp)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err)
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("resp.DataRange:        %s\n", resp.DataRange)
    fmt.Printf("resp.TotalCount:       %d\n", resp.TotalCount)
    fmt.Printf("len(resp.Certificates: %d\n", len(resp.Certificates))
    for i, c := range resp.Certificates {
        fmt.Printf("resp.Certificates[%d].Name: %s\n", i, c.Name)
    }

}

type Item struct {
    Certificates []CertificatesInfo
    DataRange    string
    TotalCount   int
}

type CertificatesInfo struct {
    Name string
}

const data = `
{
    "Certificates": [
      { "Name": "alpha"   },
      { "Name": "bravo"   },
      { "Name": "charlie" }
  ],
  "DataRange": "Certificates 1 - 1",
  "TotalCount": 3
}
`
```